# Shortcut or syntax for Angular's `ng build` command for different environments

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

As we all know, the default **ng build** command is

```
ng build --prod
```

Here we all know that the above command will build/publish the code as per environment file's configuration.

If you have multiple environments like st/uat/gr/prod then you have to use the following commands to build for the specific environment:

```
ng build --configuration st

ng build --configuration gr

ng build --configuration uat 

ng build --configuration prod
```

My question is why can't we build without using "--configuration" like below:

```
ng build --st

ng build --gr

ng build --uat 

ng build --prod
```

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: I think this is related to angular cli command

Answer (score 3):

You can't do `ng build --uat` because `--uat` is not what the `ng build` command expects.

`--prod` does not mean "production environment", it means "production build", which optimizes, aot-enables your build. You can then deploy that build to any environment.

If you want a shorter command to execute (e.g. because it's shorter to type), you can create your own "aliases" in `package.json`. The only caveat is that instead of `ng build`, you will use `npm run`.

In your `package.json`, under "scripts", add the following entries:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "version": "...",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "build:st": "ng build --configuration st",
        "build:gr": "ng build --configuration gr",
        "build:uat": "ng build --configuration uat",
        "build:prod": "ng build --configuration prod"
    },
}
```

And then, if you want a UAT build, you just need to run `npm run build:uat`. You can come up with shorter script names that fit your needs.

The bonus is that you can use this approach to combine several commands into one. For example, if you often run `ng test`, `ng lint`, `ng build` one after another, you can create a task for that under `scripts` that run all three commands at once.

Comment: Just wanted to understand that how ng build understand this ng build --prod. Actually I have configured the other environment same as production in angular.json file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand the ^ comment.

Comment: Wanted to understand that how angular cli run the ng build --prod command syntax, where just passing ( --prod ) and all the jobs done automatically but not with --uat , --st or --gr syntax.

Comment: I don't think the CLI supports options for other environments. In fact, `--prod` doesn't necessarily mean "production environment", it just means a "production build" - minified, aot-enabled etc, which you can push to any environment (dev, uat etc.). You can use the `npm run` scripts to create your own shorthands like I mentioned above.

Comment: Means we have alternative solution like npm run.